# Call Multiple Stored Procedures with the Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Zend Framework 1.7.2, MySQL and the MySQLi PDO adapter.  I would like to call multiple stored procedures during a given action.  I've found that on Windows there is a problem calling multiple stored procedures.  If you try it you get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014
>   Cannot execute queries while other
>   unbuffered queries are active.
>   Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll().
>   Alternatively, if your code is only
>   ever going to run against mysql, you
>   may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
>   attribute.

I found that to work around this issue I could just close the connection to the database after each call to a stored procedure:

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
  //If on windows close the connection
  $db->closeConnection();
}
```

This has worked well for me, however, now I want to call multiple stored procedures wrapped in a transaction.  Of course, closing the connection isn't an option in this situation, since it causes a rollback of the open transaction.  Any ideas, how to fix this problem and/or work around the issue.

- [More info about the work around](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/databases-20/how-stored-procedure-using-mysqli-pdo-successfully-662.html)
- [Bug report about the problem](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has same errors when called queries like this(variables to use in next query)

```
$db->query("SET @curr = 0.0;");
```

To fix this I've changed my config file to

```
'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'mysqli',
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I had been using the ugly workaround for more than 6 months.  I just resigned to doing complicated deletes without stored procedures, however, I'm back in business now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern of preparing, executing and then closing each $sql statement that calls a stored procedure does work.

```
public function processTeams($leagueid,$raceid,$gender)
{
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $sql = $db->prepare(sprintf("CALL addScoringTeams(%d,%d,'%s')",$leagueid,$raceid,$gender));
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->closeCursor();
    $this->logger->info(sprintf("CALL addScoringTeams(%d,%d,'%s')",$leagueid,$raceid,$gender));

    $sql1 = $db->prepare(sprintf("CALL updateScoringTeamTotals(%d)",$raceid));
    $sql1->execute();
    $sql1->closeCursor();
    $this->logger->info(sprintf("CALL updateScoringTeamTotals(%d)",$raceid));

    $sql2 = $db->prepare(sprintf("CALL updateScoringTeamClasses(%d,'%s')",$raceid,$gender));
    $sql2->execute();
    $sql2->closeCursor();
    $this->logger->info(sprintf("CALL updateScoringTeamClasses(%d,'%s')",$raceid,$gender));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepare statement . No need to change driver

```
$sql = "CALL procedure()";
$stmt = $this->db->createStatement();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```