# How can I use a stored procedure in a MySql database with Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, stored-procedures

I'm recently have learned to use Zend Framework. I did a simple CRUD application. But now I want to use a existing database for a more complex application and I want to know how I call a stored procedure in the Model, how to send parameters, how to read the results and store them in an array in PHP. Please. I appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: If you want to use stored procedures within GoDaddy hosting MySQL Database, check if you can back it up together with your database backup. From my experience, they NOT allow to backup stored procedures. It makes unacceptable for me to use them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not too hard.  Here's an example of a MySQL stored procedure with an `IN` parameter, an `OUT` parameter, and a result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN i INTEGER, OUT o INTEGER)
BEGIN
  SELECT i+10 INTO o;
  SELECT i, o;
END
```

You can call this with the `query()` method, and pass a parameter:

```
$stmt = $db->query("CALL MyProc(?, @output)", array(25));
print_r( $stmt->fetchAll() );
```

The trick is that MySQL stored procs might return multiple result sets (if the proc had multiple `SELECT` queries for instance).  So the API must advance through all result sets before you can execute another SQL query.  Or else you get the "*Commands out of sync*" error.

If you use the PDO_MySQL adapter:

```
while ($stmt->nextRowset()) { }
```

If you use the MySQLi adapter, you'll find that `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli` doesn't implement `nextRowset()`, so you have to call the  internal mysqli connection object:

```
while ($db->getConnection()->next_result()) { }
```

Once you clear the result sets, you can run subsequent SQL queries, for example to fetch the value of the procedure's `OUT` parameter:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT @output");
print_r( $stmt->fetchAll() );
```

Comment: I haven't tested calling stored procedures in other brands of database besides MySQL.

Comment: Thank you Bill.. I'll try it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from Bill. Just for completeness, if you encounter:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053
```

When using this method to get a result set from your procedure, check your arguments. I refactored a method and was passing NULLs as arguments to the procedure as the variables I'd used were out of scope. Once I'd fixed this silly mistake the problem went away (to be replaced by another):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other 
unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
```

I'm using `$stmt->fetchAll()` though. I switched to using `prepare()` and `execute()` in place of `query()`. Switching to `mysqli` from `pdo_mysql` in my Zend_Db config finally got things working for me. I found this information from the following SO question:

[Call Multiple Stored Procedures with the Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443895/call-multiple-stored-procedures-with-the-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for `ZendFramework 2` \ `Zend Expressive` using `Zend\Db` :

There is another way to do this using `createStatement()` method.

```
// prepare create statement from adapter
$stmt = $this->getAdapter()->createStatement();

$stmt->prepare('CALL myproc("myVal")');
// execute sql query
$records = $stmt->execute();
// manipulate results
if ($records instanceof ResultInterface && $records->isQueryResult()) {
    $resultSet = new ResultSet;
    $resultSet->initialize($records);
    // return records if found
    if (count($resultSet)) {
       // return array of result set
       return $resultSet->toArray();
    }
   // if no records found
   return array()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();    
    $stmt = $db->query("CALL procedure()");
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. In order to provide a good answer, you should write an explanation with the code you have provided.