# how to call stored procedure on zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

how to call mysql stored procedure on zend framework?

any body may give an example?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here:

[How can I use a stored procedure in a MySql database with Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303912/how-can-i-use-a-stored-procedure-in-a-mysql-database-with-zend-framework)

Bill has answered it.

Answer (score 3):

Let the procedure be example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example ()

BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT(licence) FROM applications WHERE `licence` > 0;
END
```

Then in your PHP code:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$stmt = $db->query("CALL sp_distinctlicence()");

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
Zend_Debug::dump($data,$label=null, $echo=false);
```