# How to create or execute MySQL Procedure in Zend-Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

In my ***Zend-Framework project***, I want to `execute a MySQL Procedure` that perform some complex search operation's.

But I don't have any idea about **`HOW to call or create PROCEDURE'S`**, if requires.

Please suggest some code.....

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: this will show you how to call it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303912/how-can-i-use-a-stored-procedure-in-a-mysql-database-with-zend-framework

Comment: I believe that this is not really a Zend_Framework related question. You simply execute an SQL query where you call/create the MySQL procedure. See here: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm

Comment: +1 Thanks Marcin, it will be very helpful for me....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it similar to how you prepare/bind normal SELECT/INSERT queries

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL procedure(:param1, :param2)');
$stmt->bindValue(':param1', 0);
$stmt->bindValue(':param2', 1000);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_db_statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) can take any piece of SQL.