# ZF2 retrieve out parameter from SP call

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, zend-framework2, out

I have created a stored procedure with following declaration:

---

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_test$$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_test(input_number INT, OUT out_number text)
BEGIN
IF (input_number = 0) THEN
          SET out_number='Errorrrr';
ELSE
          SET out_number='Testing';
END IF;
```

END$$

DELIMITER ;

---

Following is my ZF2 code to call this SP:

---

```
    $spResponse = 0;
    $prepareStmt = $this->dbGateway->createStatement ();
    $prepareStmt->prepare ( 'CALL my_test(?,?)' );
    $prepareStmt->getResource ()->bindParam ( 1, $spRequest );
    $prepareStmt->getResource ()->bindParam ( 2, $spResponse, \PDO::PARAM_STR, 2 );
    $resultSet = $prepareStmt->execute ();
```

---

This code gives me following error:

---

Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine zf2.my_test is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

---

Can somebody advice where the issue is? Also, How can i retrieve value of "OUT" parameter.

Appreciate your response and help.

Comment: Try here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303912/how-can-i-use-a-stored-procedure-in-a-mysql-database-with-zend-framework

Comment: I asked [the same question a month ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416204/accessing-mysql-stored-procedure-output-in-zend-framework-2), but without luck. I am afraid that this question might lead to the same result. Perhaps ask on [#zftalk](http://www.zftalk.com/) if you don't find an answer here. I would be interested to hear if you resolve this as I haven't tried to solve it since I asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

[This low level code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173452/how-to-execute-mysql-stored-procedure-in-zend-framework-2-with-multiple-result-s) retrieves the base PDO connection object. This way you can work the results in PHP fashion