# Stored procedure returns multiple resultset

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns 3 result sets.
When I test my procedure using MySQL workbench it gives me the 3 results.
However when I call the procedure using php I only get the first of the 3 results.  See code below

```
$sql = "call myproc();";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';
}
```

I have looked into the mysqli_next_result function but can not get it to give me the other 2 results.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ADyson, All stored procedures potentially return multiple result sets. Some procedures may even return additional result sets based on conditions in the procedure body. So a client has to process a call statement as if they had used mysqli_multi_query().

Comment: @BillKarwin so you mean next_result can work without using multi_query?

Comment: @ADyson, Yes, that's correct. See examples in this old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1304381/20860 That answer is about the Zend Framework adapter, but the same applies to PDO and Mysqli even when not using a framework.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks, that's useful. Either way I think the post is still a duplicate of at least a couple of older ones

Comment: @ADyson, Virtually every question on Stack Overflow has already been answered! LOL

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that eventually solved my problem.

```
$sql = "call myproc();";
mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql);
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';
        }
        if (mysqli_more_results($con)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    }
} while (mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
```

Thanks everyone for your help on this.